# Pyspark - Read Log Analytics table through a Synapse Notebook

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to create a pyspark dataframe reading a log analytics table from Synapse Notebook.

I used this code but without success:

```
df_lg_tb = spark.read.format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource") \
    .option("kustoCluster", "https://<workspace-id>.ods.opinsights.azure.com") \
    .option("kustoDatabase", "<my-log-analytics-database-name>") \
    .option("kustoQuery", "AzureActivity|take 10") \
    .option("kustoAADUserId", "<workspace-id>") \
    .option("kustoAADPassword", "<workspace-key>") \
    .load()
```

Does anyone know another method in order to connect?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the above code, make sure you have added the log analytics workspace connection

```
https://ade.loganalytics.io/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourcegroups/<resource_group_name>/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/<workspace_name>
```

to the kustos cluster like below.

[image]

Check you have all the required necessary permissions and roles and try to run the above code.

If that doesn't work you can try the below approaches as a workaround.

- Use Python SDK to read the table data by passing the query. Go through this [Documentation samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/azure-monitor-query_1.1.1/sdk/monitor/azure-monitor-query#logs-query) to know about it.
- First **Export the log analytics table data to a storage account** and then **read the data from the storage account to synapse notebook by mounting**. Refer this [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-observability-blog/how-to-analyze-data-exported-from-log-analytics-data-using/ba-p/2547888) by @**Shemer Steinlauf** for the detailed steps.